# Increment ID# by 1 if Same month ArrayFormula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, countif

I'm trying to set up an array formula in a google sheet to save filling in a simple formula for ID#s.

The sheet is populated by a google form, so it receives a timestamp.  Let's say these are orders.

If the month of the order matches that of the previous I want to increase the ID# by one, essentially counting this months orders. The complete ID# is actually made up of several factors, the order count being just one of them (so that they are unique), but for the sake of this exercise, I'll keep it simple.

If the month of the order does not match the previous, then safe to say we've entered the new month and the ID should restart at 01.

I have a column that has the extracted month from the timestamp.  So the data looks like this:

```
 A       B
ID#    MONTH
1        1

2        1

3        1

4        1

5        1

6        1

1        2

2        2

3        2

1        3 

2        3

3        3

4        3
```

I can't get the arrayformula to work!  I've tried numerous `countIfs` and `Ifs`, something like

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(len(B2:B),if(B3:B<>B2:B,1,A2:A+1),""))
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for this?

I found it hard to Google for and have tried a few search terms!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B1:B<>"", COUNTIFS(B1:B, B1:B, ROW(B1:B), "<="&ROW(B1:B)), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for this (and the edit)  it's a great help, I will study it and try and understand how it works, too :)